# Rearrange grid items inside LazyVGrid without the long press (iOS wallpaper way)

Tags: ios, swiftui, drag-and-drop

I want to achieve a similar effect for the drag and drop to the iOS wallpaper, ideally without calculating the absolute item position on the screen

I was using .onDrop and .onDrag with DropDelegate, but it required item to be long pressed

[iOS wallpaper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDviZ.jpg)

The current way that requires the long press:

```html
LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 10) {
  ForEach(viewModel.apps) { app in
    AppButton(app: app) {
      // button action
    }
    .shadow(radius: 5)
    .onDrag({
      viewModel.currentApp = app
      return NSItemProvider(contentsOf: URL(string: "\(app.id)")!)!
     })
     .onDrop(
        of: [.image],
        delegate: DropViewDelegate(app: app, viewModel: viewModel)
      )
  }
}
```

```html
struct DropViewDelegate: DropDelegate {
    var app: AppItem
    var viewModel: AppsViewModel

    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
        let fromIndex = viewModel.apps.firstIndex { (app) -> Bool in
            return app.id == viewModel.currentApp?.id
        } ?? 0

        let toIndex = viewModel.apps.firstIndex { (app) -> Bool in
            return app.id == self.app.id
        } ?? 0

        if fromIndex != toIndex{
            withAnimation(.default){
                let fromApp = viewModel.apps[fromIndex]
                viewModel.apps[fromIndex] = viewModel.apps[toIndex]
                viewModel.apps[toIndex] = fromApp
            }
        }
    }

    func dropUpdated(info: DropInfo) -> DropProposal? {
        return DropProposal(operation: .move)
    }
}
```

Comment: Write the code itself what you've wrote already and what is not working.
be more **specific**.